# Launch the default microsoft windows weather app from my UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm currently working on UWP Apps, I want to open the default microsoft weather app from my UWP app, Actually I tried the below code to open the weather app

```
 <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="7" 
                         Margin="0,10,0,0" NavigateUri="ms-windows-store://pdp/?PFN=Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
                             FontSize="14"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

but it firstly open the store and then in store it open the weather app because i'm using ms-windows-store: But i want to open the weather app directly from my app. Is it possible or not.

Thanks & regards,
Cristina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly open the weather app by using the following deeplink:

```
msnweather:
```

You will have to change your code to:

```
<HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="7" 
                     Margin="0,10,0,0" NavigateUri="msnweather:"
                         FontSize="14"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Just to add... you can also use bingweather: